# Adding Four numbers and finding the Average in Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, output, addition, average

Trying to broaden my programming skills. Done python, c++, java, and a little bit of cobol but assembly is confusing the hell out of me. Tried to make a program that prompts and inputs four grades with separate dialog boxes and calculates the sum and the average (sum/4) of the grades. Code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
number1 DWORD   ?
number2 DWORD   ?
number3 DWORD   ?
number4 DWORD   ?
four    DWORD   4
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter first number", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter second number", 0
prompt3 BYTE    "Enter third number",0
prompt4 BYTE    "Enter fourth number",0
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
resultLbl BYTE  "The sum is", 0
resultAvg BYTE  "The average is",0
sum     BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0
avg     BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input   prompt1, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters
        atod    string          ; convert to integer
        mov     number1, eax    ; store in memory

        input   prompt2, string, 40      ; repeat for second number
        atod    string
        mov     number2, eax

        input   prompt3, string, 40
        atod    string
        mov     number3, eax

        input   prompt4, string, 40
        atod    string
        mov     number4, eax

        mov     eax, number1    ; first number to EAX
        add     eax, number2    ; add second number to EAX
        add     eax, number3    ; add third number to EAX
        add     eax, number4    ; add fourth number to EAX
        mov     ax, eax         ; copy eax's value into ax (does this take eax's value away from eax?)
        mov     al, four        ; put's 4 into al
        idiv    al,             ; divides sum by ax(4)
        dota    avg, ax         ; convert to ASCII characters
        dtoa    sum, eax        ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, sum          ; output label and sum
        output resultAvg, avg               ; output label and avg

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. It compiles and runs but only asks for 2 numbers and then returns the sum of those 2 numbers. Any and all help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can't say what's causing only 2 numbers to be requested and only the sum to be output without your `io.h`.  Where did that come from?  The code makes sense.

The `ax` register is only 16 bits.  If your macro expects a number in `eax`, you're broken.

You probably want a 32-bit dividend and result.  It's simplest just to stick with the 32-bit instructions:

```
cdq               ; sign extends eax into the edx register
idiv four         ; divide edx:eax by four.  Result is in eax.
```

It's even simpler to shift right 2 places! This also divides by 4.

```
sar ax, 2
```

Comment: So where would i put `cdq` and `idiv four`? Would i take out the `mov al, four`and `idiv al,` and replace it with `cdq` and `idiv four`? I think thats what you're getting at

Comment: @user38254 Yes.  Delete 3 instructions.  Insert the shift or the division.  But this will not fix your i/o problems.